# Varying number of generic parameters based on a feature

Tags: generics, rust, enums

I am using Rust 1.62.0 and would like to add a variant to an `enum` based on whether a feature is enabled.

The following compiles without issues.

```rust
enum MyEnum<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> {
    Always,
    #[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
    OnlyWithFeature(T),
}
```

So I thought that all I need to do is to "guard" `T` with a `cfg` attribute wherever it occurs.
However, the second `T` in the following seems to be an issue.

```rust
impl<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> MyEnum<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self::Always
    }
}
```

The error messages are as follows.

With no features:

```
 --> src/main.rs:7:74
  |
7 | impl<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> MyEnum<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> {
  |                                                                          ^
  |
help: expressions must be enclosed in braces to be used as const generic arguments
  |
7 | impl<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> MyEnum<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] { T }> {
  |                                                                          +   +

error[E0107]: this enum takes 0 generic arguments but 1 generic argument was supplied
 --> src/main.rs:7:38
  |
7 | impl<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> MyEnum<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> {
  |                                      ^^^^^^-------------------------------- help: remove these generics
  |                                      |
  |                                      expected 0 generic arguments
  |
note: enum defined here, with 0 generic parameters
 --> src/main.rs:1:6
  |
1 | enum MyEnum<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> {
  |      ^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0107`.
```

With `--features my-feature`:

```
error: invalid const generic expression
 --> src/main.rs:7:74
  |
7 | impl<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> MyEnum<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> {
  |                                                                          ^
  |
help: expressions must be enclosed in braces to be used as const generic arguments
  |
7 | impl<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> MyEnum<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] { T }> {
  |                                                                          +   +

error[E0747]: constant provided when a type was expected
 --> src/main.rs:7:74
  |
7 | impl<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> MyEnum<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> {
  |                                                                          ^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0747`.
```

I have the impression that the compiler tries to parse `T` as a const generic, so I guess the `cfg` attribute doesn't belong there...

Guarding the whole `impl` block seems to work fine, for example the following compiles.

```rust
#[cfg(not(feature="my-feature"))]
impl MyEnum {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self::Always
    }
}
#[cfg(feature="my-feature")]
impl<T> MyEnum<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self::Always
    }
}
```

However, this would essentially require me to write a big `impl` block twice.

Is there a simpler way to use a different number of generic parameters based on a feature?

Comment: You should look into building out a macro to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Using this form in the rest of your code will be a painful experience. When you use the "feature" you'll end up with code duplication everywhere without some helper macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `macro_rules!` declarative macro to prevent needing to duplicate code:

```rust
enum MyEnum<#[cfg(feature="my-feature")] T> {
    Always,
    #[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
    OnlyWithFeature(T),
}

// Produces impl blocks for feature enabled and disabled
macro_rules! impl_MyEnum_with_without_feature {
    // Matches `impl MyEnum` followed by a block
    { impl MyEnum $implementations:tt } => {
        #[cfg(not(feature="my-feature"))]
        impl MyEnum $implementations
        
        #[cfg(feature="my-feature")]
        impl<T> MyEnum<T> $implementations
    }
}

impl_MyEnum_with_without_feature! {
    impl MyEnum {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            Self::Always
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you will still need to create a separate impl block for anything that needs the generic parameter.

Comment: I find using such macros rather unsatisfying (in particular because they introduce non-standard syntax), but I guess I don't really have a choice at this point.

I will need to instantiate these parameters at other places like function arguments too, so in the end I wrote the following macros to name the correct type based on the feature:
`macro_rules! my_enum {($_:ty) => {MyEnum}}` when `#[cfg(not(feature="my-feature"))]`,
`macro_rules! my_enum {($t:ty) => {MyEnum<$t>}}` when `#[cfg(feature="my-feature")]`.